# How to make a django api view accessible to all users?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I'm creating a Django API view for a game by extending the rest_framework.views.APIView class.

It's very likely that most users will not be authenticated. How can I enforce that?
As far as I know there is no permissions.IsNotAuthenticated or similar.

This is the part where I have trouble in my view, where I am trying to create a game round and game session object. I have tried working around this issue by creating a pseudo-user if the user isn't authenticated:

```
if not isinstance(request.user, CustomUser):
            current_user = '1'
        else:
            current_user = request.user
```

However, I keep getting this Value error message:

`Cannot assign "'1'": "Gamesession.user" must be a "CustomUser" instance.`

Below the code section from **views.py**

```
current_score = 0
        if not isinstance(request.user, CustomUser):
            current_user = '1'
        else:
            current_user = request.user

        gamesession = Gamesession.objects.create(
            id=controller.generate_random_id(Gamesession),
            user=current_user,
            gametype=gametype,
            created=datetime.now()
        )

        gameround = Gameround.create({
            'id': controller.generate_random_id(Gameround),
            'user': current_user,
            'gamesession': gamesession,
            'created': datetime.now(),
            'score': current_score,
        })
        gameround_serializer = GameroundSerializer(gameround)
```

Answer (score 0):

You create this with:

```
current_score = 0
if not isinstance(request.user, CustomUser):
    current_user_id = 1
else:
    current_user_id = request.user.pk

gamesession = Gamesession.objects.create(
    id=controller.generate_random_id(Gamesession),
    user_id=current_user_id,
    gametype=gametype,
    created=datetime.now()
)

gameround = Gameround.objects.create(
    id=controller.generate_random_id(Gameround),
    user_id=current_user_id,
    gamesession=gamesession,
    created=datetime.now(),
    score=current_score,
)
gameround_serializer = GameroundSerializer(gameround)
```

This requires that there is a `CustomUser` with primary key `1` and you thus link all "anonymous" users to that specific user.

Comment: I have tried this and then specified current_user = CustomUser().objects.all().filter(id=current_user_id) but I get the AttributeError 'Manager isn't accessible via CustomUser instances'

Comment: @CarinaTheBookworm: but you should not filter at all, if you want to fetch the current user, you can do that with `current_user = CustomUser.objects.filter(id=current_user_id)` so *without* brackets for `CustomUser`, but you do not need to fetch such instance, by using `user_id` instead of `user` when you *create* items, you can pass its primary key...

Comment: I have taken it out now. I have run into a different error but the user problem seems to not be there anymore. Thank you.